# Display multiple markers with unique infowindows on Google Maps

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to store create unique infowindow for each Marker stored on a list. This is the code.

```
     let displayedMarkerList = [];
    
        for (let markerListItem = 0; l < markerListItem.length; markerListItem++) {
          let markerDisplayObj = placeMarkerByType(    // here I create the markers and place them on the map
            markerList[markerListItem].latLong,
            markerList[markerListItem].markerType
          );
          displayedMarkerList.push(markerDisplayObj);    //here I store the marker objects on a list
        }
    
      
        for (
          let displayedMarkerListItem = 0;
          displayedMarkerListItem < displayedMarkerList.length;
          displayedMarkerListItem++
        )
        
          {
            displayedMarkerList[displayedMarkerListItem].addListener("click", function(displayedMarkerListItem)  {
              return function(){
              infowindowAllMarkers.open({
                anchor: marker,
                map,
                shouldFocus: true,
              });
          }(displayedMarkerListItem)});
          }
  }
```

Basically I recive a list of coordinates and marker types, I use placeMarkerByType to create the markers, I store the marker objects on a list and then I try to add an event listener for each marker in displayedMarkerList.
The problem is that it only adds the event listener on the last item.

I found on internet that I need to use a closure. I tried to implement it but I get the same result. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I added this instead of marker on the anchor attribute and it works now.

Can be marked by solved

Comment: Dear @Vlad, I see that you are new here, welcome to stackoverflow.
Your answer in not clear, "I added this instead".
Can you please answer the question in the answer and provide information and details that can be useful for other users.
Please check the manual of how to answer questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer